# Android SurfaceView not showing video after onResume

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am trying to build a media player in android which will play http streams, I have customized the https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry player for my needs, now only one issue remains, during playback, if user receives phone call, the video player should store the current position and resume it after call, I have managed to do it, but after phone call all I can hear is audio, no video is shown, I know it has something to do with SurfaceHolder.Callback but I am not sure how to make it work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In SurfaceCreated, set the display surface of the player - setDisplay(holder)